# Bronze Stars vs. Power Stars

Tags: super-mario-galaxy-2

In Super Mario Galaxy 2, if you use the Cosmic Guide to finish a level, you are informed that you will receive a "Bronze Star" instead of a "Power Star". I assumed that meant that it wouldn't increase your total Star count, however, when I finished the level in question (Flip Swap Galaxy's Think Before You Shake level) using the Cosmic Guide (and thereby getting the Bronze Star), my Star count still went up.

Is there a benefit to getting the Power Stars over the Bronze Stars? Or can I essentially get the game to play itself (when available) with no real detriment?

Comment: I would think spending $50 on a game to then turn around and let the game play itself would be as real of a detriment as you could get.

Comment: *laughs* Point taken, although for levels that I have been trying for a long time to beat, it is nice to be able to get past it, and then I have the option to go back and get things later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After you get 120 Power Stars there's a whole other quest to go through — and it's way better than the second quest in SMG1. You won't ever get to see it, though, if you stay satisfied with those Bronze Stars.

Answer (score 3):

The stars are exactly the same except being in a different color, and thus the Bronze Star being more dull to have then the Power Star. So you could essentially get the game to play itself with no loss as you said.

[Source](http://www.mariowiki.com/Bronze_Star)

Answer (score 0):

There is a very subtle difference between the two other than colour,
that being if you get the the final galaxy (Grandmaster galaxy) you will not be able to play it with even one bronze star.